# wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I think there is a problem in output parameter code.But I don't know how to solve this..Can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code?

Error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_WF_GET_REQUESTDETAILS' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

My code

```cs
public DataResponse<DataTable> GetRequestCount(string Usercode)
{
    try
    {
        var paramList = new List<OracleParameter>();
        paramList.Add(new OracleParameter("P_IN_KEY", "GET_REQUEST_COUNT"));
        paramList.Add(new OracleParameter("P_USER_CODE", Usercode));
        OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter("P_OUT_OPEN", OracleType.Cursor);
        OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("P_OUT_APPROVED", OracleType.Cursor);
        OracleParameter param2 = new OracleParameter("P_OUT_REJECTED", OracleType.Cursor);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        paramList.Add(param);
        paramList.Add(param1);
        paramList.Add(param2);
        var data = SPExcute("SP_WF_GET_REQUESTDETAILS", paramList);
        return data;  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.LogInfo();
        return new DataResponse<DataTable>(DataResponseCode.InvaildInputs);
    }
}
```

My stored procedure

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_WF_GET_REQUESTDETAILS (P_IN_KEY      IN VARCHAR2,
                                                  P_USER_CODE varchar2,
                                                  P_OUT_OPEN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                                  P_OUT_APPROVED OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                                  P_OUT_REJECTED OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                                  P_OUT_TBL OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN
    IF P_IN_KEY='GET_OPENREQUEST' THEN
    BEGIN
      OPEN P_OUT_TBL FOR
      SELECT A.REQUEST_NO AS Request_No,
        A.REQUEST_DATE AS Request_Date,
        A.CATEGORY_CODE AS Category_Code,
        A.STATUS AS Status
        FROM WF_TBL_TRN_REQUEST_HEADER A
        WHERE A.CREATED_BY=P_USER_CODE AND (A.STATUS='OPEN' OR A.STATUS like 'APPROVE LEVEL%');      
    END;
    ELSIF P_IN_KEY='GET_APROVEDREQUEST' THEN 
      BEGIN
        OPEN P_OUT_TBL FOR
          SELECT A.REQUEST_NO AS Request_No,
            A.REQUEST_DATE AS Request_Date,
            A.CATEGORY_CODE AS Category_Code,
            A.STATUS AS Status
          FROM WF_TBL_TRN_REQUEST_HEADER A
            WHERE A.CREATED_BY=P_USER_CODE AND (A.STATUS='APPROVED');   
    END;
    ELSIF P_IN_KEY='GET_REJECTEDREQUEST' THEN
       BEGIN
        OPEN P_OUT_TBL FOR
          SELECT A.REQUEST_NO AS Request_No,
            A.REQUEST_DATE AS Request_Date,
            A.CATEGORY_CODE AS Category_Code,
            A.STATUS AS Status
          FROM WF_TBL_TRN_REQUEST_HEADER A
            WHERE A.CREATED_BY=P_USER_CODE AND (A.STATUS='REJECTED' OR A.STATUS like 'REJECTED LEVEL%');  
    END;
    ELSIF P_IN_KEY='GET_REQUEST_COUNT' THEN
      BEGIN
        OPEN P_OUT_OPEN FOR
          SELECT COUNT(*) Open_Request_Count FROM WF_TBL_TRN_REQUEST_HEADER A WHERE A.CREATED_BY=P_USER_CODE AND (A.STATUS='OPEN' OR A.STATUS like 'APPROVE LEVEL%');
      END;
      BEGIN
        OPEN P_OUT_APPROVED FOR
          
          SELECT COUNT(*) Approved_Request_Count FROM WF_TBL_TRN_REQUEST_HEADER A WHERE A.CREATED_BY=P_USER_CODE AND (A.STATUS='APPROVED');
          
      END;
      BEGIN
        OPEN P_OUT_REJECTED FOR
          
          SELECT COUNT(*) Rejected_Request_Count FROM WF_TBL_TRN_REQUEST_HEADER A WHERE A.CREATED_BY=P_USER_CODE AND (A.STATUS='REJECTED' OR A.STATUS like 'REJECTED LEVEL%');
      END;
    END IF;
END SP_WF_GET_REQUESTDETAILS;
```

This is my complete stored procedure

Comment: It seems you're calling the stored procedure with 5 parameters, ensure the stored procedure actually take 5 parameters.

Comment: The code for your stored procedure is incomplete

Comment: Actually here I have added part of the procedure. Now I've added the entire stored procedure

Comment: You seem to miss the `P_OUT_TBL` parameter in your c# code

Comment: P_OUT_TBL is only for other P_IN_KEY values.  Not for P_IN_KEY='GET_REQUEST_COUNT' .

Comment: That doesn't mean you can omit it from the parameter list when calling the stored procedure.

Comment: Can I use 4 out parameters in procedure? Is this right?

Comment: I've added P_OUT_TBL. But I got ORA-24338: statement handle not executed

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your SP line 2 change from: "P_USER_CODE varchar2" to "P_USER_CODE IN varchar2" ?

Comment: yeah, I've missed that. But after this too I got the same error ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_WF_GET_REQUESTDETAILS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored